# How to test a bootloader

Tags: testing, assembly, virtual-machine, nasm, bootloader

I have a little bootloader file (512 B) that I would like to test without destroying my computer. Are there any virtual machine programs that would allow me to do this?

Comment: 512 bytes or megabytes? I realize I am an old timer programmer for feeling that 512MB is not that little ;o)

Comment: @Seki oops, thats a typo! Fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Virtualbox, Bochs and VMWare work quite well for this.

If you are creating the bootloader and plan to jump into SVGA graphics from your bootloader I'd recommend that you look at Virtualbox; I've had lots of incompatibilities with some SVGA modes in VMWare that are very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: I have virtualbox, but I didnt know I could do this. Are there any resources that would help me with this?

Comment: Ok I've figured it out. Thanks!